# Cannot read property 'context' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been going through the Egghead "Build your first production quality React app" and everything's going fine until lesson 17, where you're supposed to use `context`to create your own home made router component. As far as I can tell, I do exactly the same thing as in the lesson, but I get this console error when I click on one of the `Link` component:

```
Link.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'context' of null
at handleClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33792:12)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17162:17)
at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16945:22)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16968:6)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16356:23)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16367:11)
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEachAccumulated (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17265:10)
at Object.processEventQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16570:8)
at runEventQueueInBatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24192:19)
```

The link component looks like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Link extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    route: React.PropTypes.string,
    linkHandler: React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.linkHandler(this.props.to)
  }

  render() {
    const activeClass = this.context.route === this.props.to ? 'active' : '';
    return <a href="#" className={activeClass} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</a>
  }
}

Link.propTypes = {
  to: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

And the Router component looks like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const getCurrentPath = () => {
  const path = document.location.pathname;
  return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'));
}

export class Router extends Component {
  state = {
    route: getCurrentPath()
  }

  handleLinkClick = (route) => {
    this.setState({ route }); // same as { route: route }
    history.pushState(null, '', route);
  }

  static childContextTypes = {
    route: React.PropTypes.string,
    linkHandler: React.PropTypes.func,
  };

  getchildContext() {
    return {
      route: this.state.route,
      linkHandler: this.handleLinkClick,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}
```

Any idea of what could be causing the problem?

Thanks for any pointer in the right direction!

EDIT:

After following the advices I got (thanks!), I bound the `handleClick` in a constructor (same result with an arrow function) and verified that the function is called as expected, but now I get a different error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.context.linkHandler is not a function
at Link.handleClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:33707:21)
at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17162:17)
at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16945:22)
at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16968:6)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16356:23)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16367:11)
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEachAccumulated (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17265:10)
at Object.processEventQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16570:8)
at runEventQueueInBatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24192:19)
```

Comment: You need to bind this to handleClick.  You can either do this in a constructor or in onClick (not recommended).  onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} . Or use an arrow function for handleClick.  const handleClick = () = > { }.

Comment: ^^ This is the answer to the question posed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to needing to bind a function to `this`, this error can also occur if you've bound a function that no longer exists in the class:

```
export class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.functionDoesNotExistAnymore = this.functionDoesNotExistAnymore.bind(this);
    }

    // functionDoesNotExistAnymore() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution for a super misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you are using ES6 with React. You need to bind the handleClick function to the context of the React component. You can use arrow function at component definition to bind the context like below

```
export class Link extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    route: React.PropTypes.string,
    linkHandler: React.PropTypes.func,
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.context.linkHandler(this.props.to)
  }

  render() {
    const activeClass = this.context.route === this.props.to ? 'active' : '';
    return <a href="#" className={activeClass} onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</a>
  }
}
```

or you can bind it in th constructor like

```
export class Link extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }

   ...

}
```

or you can bind it at the time of calling

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>

or

onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a clear answer to this question, the others have a great deal of extra information that can lead you astray.

Quoting

> You need to bind this to handleClick. You can either do this in a
>   constructor or in onClick (not recommended).
>   onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} . Or use an arrow function for
>   handleClick. const handleClick = () = > { }.

– [Norm Crandall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6117649/norm-crandall) (from comments)